# REST Service Error 405: Method not allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, httpresponsemessage

My Get Works perfectly, but my update and delete give me 405 Errors.
Here is my Web.config and Controller. Sorry for the bad formatting. I've tried a lot of different thing but I am unsure why I am getting 405 Errors. 
my app works with my other REST Service so I know it can perform CRUD and that the issue is my Service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="Username" value="Xamarin" />
        <add key="Password" value="Pa$$w0rd" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=4.0.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule,Microsoft.AI.Web" />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
            <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
            <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" 
  type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebDAV" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    </system.webServer>
```

Here is my Controller

```
public class ResponseItemsController : BaseApiController
{
    static readonly IwellService wellService = new wellService(new 
    wellRepository());

    [HttpGet]
    [BasicAuthentication(RequireSsl = false)]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        return base.BuildSuccessResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
        wellService.GetData());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [BasicAuthentication(RequireSsl = false)]
    public HttpResponseMessage Create([FromBody]ResponseItem item)
    {
        try
        {
            if (item == null ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Name__c) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Question_1__c))
            {
                return base.BuildErrorResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ErrorCode.wellItemNameAndNotesRequired.ToString());
            }

            // Determine if the ID already exists
            var itemExists = wellService.DoesItemExist(item.ID);
            if (itemExists)
            {
                return base.BuildErrorResult(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, ErrorCode.wellItemIDInUse.ToString());
            }
            wellService.InsertData(item);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return base.BuildErrorResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ErrorCode.CouldNotCreateItem.ToString());
        }

        return base.BuildSuccessResult(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [BasicAuthentication(RequireSsl = false)]
    public HttpResponseMessage Edit(string id, [FromBody]ResponseItem item)
    {
        try
        {
            if (item == null ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Name__c) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Mentor_name__c))
            {
                return base.BuildErrorResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ErrorCode.wellItemNameAndNotesRequired.ToString());
            }

            var wellItem = wellService.Find(id);
            if (wellItem != null)
            {
                wellService.UpdateData(item);
            }
            else
            {
                return base.BuildErrorResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ErrorCode.RecordNotFound.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return base.BuildErrorResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ErrorCode.CouldNotUpdateItem.ToString());
        }

        return base.BuildSuccessResult(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    [BasicAuthentication(RequireSsl = false)]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            var wellItem = wellService.Find(id);
            if (wellItem != null)
            {
                wellService.DeleteData(id);
            }
            else
            {
                return base.BuildErrorResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ErrorCode.RecordNotFound.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return base.BuildErrorResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ErrorCode.CouldNotDeleteItem.ToString());
        }

        return base.BuildSuccessResult(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
}
```

}

Here is my routing WebApiconfig/Routeconfig. I've tried using [Route("api/responseitems/")] for the controller and then [Route("api/responseitems/{id}")] for the methods but same issue of 405 errors. My written in exceptions are codes are just 404,400,200.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}


public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are catching exceptions and throw away the valuable exception information. If I were you, I would first fix this and see what _actually_ happens.

Comment: **Never** catch an exception just to throw it away.  At a *minimum*, log it.

Comment: How are your routes configured?  `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` don't work with convention-based routing, and I see no `Route` attributes decorating your methods.

Comment: I've added my routing above for you to see

Comment: @Amy I added my route classes. I forgot to mention that my create method works along with my Get.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your calling mechanism from your application. Can you use correct Http verb while calling your API.

Or place your complete endpoints with your method type so that I may further help you out.

Comment: Chances are the OP is no longer in need of help. It's been two and a half years since they asked the question ;-)